# Predefine a struct in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I try to do this in C :

```
typedef struct s_match_fptr
{
  char *str;
  int  (*funcptr)(t_client *client, char **command);
} t_match_fptr;

typedef struct s_client
{
  int socket_fd;
  int port;
  char *server_ip;
  struct sockaddr_in s_in;
  t_match_fptr  *db;
} t_client;
```

The point is I try to declare a function pointer that takes in parameter a `t_client` struct in my `t_match_ptr` struct.

Also, my struct `t_client` have an array of `t_match_ptr`.

For simplify, A need to be declared after B AND B needs to be declared after A.

So, is there a way to "predeclare" `t_client` before the declaration of `t_match_ptr`?

Thank you and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward declaration.
Add at the beginning: `typedef struct s_client t_client;`

Now the compiler will know the type `t_client` when encountered in `s_match_fptr`.
Note, the type must be used only by reference in the `s_match_fptr` definition (i.e. using a pointer). This way the compiler doesn't need to know the actual contents of the type when parsing the code.

Comment: It's compiling , thank you so much ;)
How can i pass the topic on solved, im new into stackoverflow ?